# CMAKE - include directories with special character

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am currently changing the build system of my project to CMake.

In my `CmakeLists.txt` i need to add the following directory to my include path :

```
RSA/PKCS#1v15
```

To do so i tried the following :

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/RSA/PKCS#1v15)
```

This fails because of the `#` character being the cmake commenting symbol.

How can i bypass this behavior ?

Comment: `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/RSA/PKCS\#1v15)`?

Comment: ... or wrap the argument into double quotes: `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/RSA/PKCS#1v15"`.

Comment: I tried both and this does not work : the generated makefiles containing `/RSA/PKCS#1v15/rsa_pkcs1v15.h`